# Which variables to set under which in my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I am a newbie to mysql , Just want to know which variables should i set under which blocks , 
I mean what variables should be under

> [mysql]

What variables under

> [mysqld],[mysqladmin],...

and so on

help  is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You should set all global variables values under [mysqld] section of `my.cnf` file and restart server to have effect of changed values on your server.

Comment: thank you , find can you provide me a link explaining this section

Answer (score 0):

Those blocks are for the different programs within any mysql installation.

For example, the `mysqld` and `mysql` groups apply to the mysqld server and the mysql client program, respectively.

You might want to have a look into the [manual pages titled "using option files"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) for more details.